# Automapper map from one object to nested objects

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

What is the best way to map inner objects with Automapper 2.0

1. Use the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634253/automapper-how-to-map-nested-object-from-an-objectid) (Automapper 1.0)
2. Create a Custom Value Resolvers
3. ?

   ```
   public class DTOObject
   {
       // MainObject
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }

       // SubObject (TopObject)
       public string TopText { get; set; }
       public string TopFont { get; set; }

       // SubObject (BottomObject)
       public string BottomText { get; set; }
       public string BottomFont { get; set; }
   }

   public class MainObject
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public SubObject TopObject { get; set; }
       public SubObject BottomObject { get; set; }
   }

   public class SubObject
   {
       public string SubPropText { get; set; }
       public string SubPropFont { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Custom Value Resolvers

```
    public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<DTOObject, SubObject>
    {
        protected override SubObject ResolveCore(DTOObject source)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<DTOObject, SubObject>(source);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have control of the design of the DTOObject?

Comment: Yes, and no this is a old data base that is in heavy use.

Comment: Which direction are you trying to go, DTOObject to MainObject or MainObject to DTOObject?

Comment: Probably best to use `Mapper.CreateMap<DTOObject, MainObject>().ForMember(d => d.TopObject, mc => mc.MapFrom(s => new SubObject(){ SubPropText = s.TopText, SubPropFont = s.TopFont } ));`

Comment: Also note, in your CustomResolver you shouldn't call Mapper.Map() you should create the SubObject using the properties from the source and return that.

Comment: why not call a sub mapping that takes in the same source object and returns the SubObject I need?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7308/discussion-between-bjarki-heioar-and-sean-woodward)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me it was possible to use just MapFrom (without ResolveUsing what gives you a chance to use this mapping with IQueryable extensions).
So you will get the following in the Automapper configuration:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DTOObject, SubObject>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SubPropText, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.BottomText))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SubPropFont, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.BottomFont));

Mapper.CreateMap<DTOObject, MainObject>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TopPart, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BottomPart, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x));
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating my own value resolvers for any SubObjects of `MainObject` that come from `DTOObject`.

```
public class PartResolver<T> : ValueResolver<DTOObject, T>
{
    protected override T ResolveCore(DTOObject source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<T>(source);
    }
}
```

Then in my Automapper config I create a map from the `DTOObject` to `SubObject` and use the ValueResolver to map that object into the `MainObject`

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DTOObject, SubObject>();

Mapper.CreateMap<DTOObject, MainObject>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TopPart, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<PartResolver<SubObject>>())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BottomPart, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<PartResolver<SubObject>>());
```

Answer (score 1):

**ResolveUsing** is not available with latest version of AutoMapper. So only option left is to use **MapFrom**. (use @ZedRoth solution).