# Mapping to a custom type which has an internal constructor

Tags: c#, .net, exception, automapper, tridion

We are trying to map an object - a Tridion Outbound Email Contact - which has a custom dictionary type property with an internal constructor - ExtendedDetailCollection

It's fine mapping from the object onto a Viewmodel

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact,ContactViewModel>()
    .ForMember(x=>x.Name, m=>m.MapFrom(x=>x.ExtendedDetails["Name"].StringValue))
```

but the other way does not work

We have tried:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ContactViewModel,Contact>()
    .ForMember(x=>x.ExtendedDetails["Name"].Value, m => m.MapFrom(x=>x.Name));
```

but that throws a runtime exception.

**Edit:** The message of the exception is:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException : Custom configuration for
>   members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.

We have also tried the various type converters and value resolvers but none allow us to get at the object being mapped to, which is what we need to get access to in order to map the ExtendedDetails object.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ContactViewModel,Contact>()
    .ForMember(x=>x.ExtendedDetails, m => ????);
```

Is there a pattern for this or is it easier just to use a static method?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting, is the problem that AutoMapper cannot instantiate an instance of that dictionary?

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110815/automapper-map-from-one-object-to-nested-objects I used a Custom Value Resolvers to map from inner objects.

Comment: @TrevorPilley Yes that is the issue. I'll update with the exception now. There's no way to instantiate the extended details dictionary directly and Value Resolvers expect to create the class themselves if it is a class. I can't find a way to pass the ExtendedDetails property as an initial value.

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett is the dictionary in a library which you control the source for?

Answer (score 1):

If ExtendedDetails is a class you need to createMap for this class and then individual property like Name of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we've tried that and it doesn't work because of the internal constructor.

Comment: I guess you should ask Tridion to change that constructor's visibility then - or create some sort of wrapper around that constructor that you would be able to call.

Comment: @Ram, may we convince you to committing to the Tridion SE site proposal, your help there will be appreciated http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2

Comment: @ Bart - What kind of help you are expecting from me?

Comment: @Ram, currently nothing more than following the link in my previous comment and clicking on the commit button. We are trying to get a  tridion.stackexchange.com site launched and your help in there will be valued.